# Why doesn’t the UN peacekeeping mission fight back against Hizbollah on the Israeli border?

Tags: israel, united-nations, lebanon, peacekeeping

Recently Hizbollah [has been escalating](https://www.jns.org/middle-east/israel-lebanon-border/23/8/29/314193/) pressure on the Israeli border, possibly triggering a new conflict. But why aren’t they being repelled by UN forces before Israel has a chance to respond? There are over 10,000 UN soldiers on the Lebanon-Israeli border and one would expect them to be the first line of defense before Israel needs to bring in their own troops.

Comment: Not my DV, but I suspect that UNIFIL like most other UN forces only has  a mandate to respond with force if they are fired upon.

Comment: @Fizz then... what's even the point of them being there?!

Comment: What was the point of them being in Bosnia etc.? Same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was slightly wrong in my first comment. [According](https://www.reuters.com/world/un-vote-lebanon-peacekeeping-force-delayed-france-us-uae-argue-2023-08-30/) to Reuters,

> UNIFIL's mandate was expanded in 2006, following a month-long war between Israel and Hezbollah, to allow peacekeepers to help the Lebanese army keep parts of the south free of weapons or armed personnel other than those of the Lebanese state.
>
> That has sparked friction with Hezbollah, which effectively controls southern Lebanon despite the presence of the Lebanese army. Hezbollah is a heavily armed party that is Lebanon's most powerful political force.

So technically, UNIFIL seems mandated to disarm any Hezbollah fighters it encounters. In practice that probably doesn't happen at scale for pragmatic reasons. One of them being that UNIFIL isn't [too actively] searching for Hezbollah fighters, as its commander of 2006 [said](https://reliefweb.int/report/lebanon/un-peacekeeping-force-rules-out-task-disarm-lebanons-hezbollah) and which probably hasn't changed since.

> The commander of the UN peacekeeping force in Lebanon French General Alain Pellegrini said [...] that his troops will not try to disarm Hezbollah which is a matter for the Lebanese government.
>
> [...]
>
> "Our mission is to maintain a zone between the Blue Line and the Litani (River) where there is no illegal army and from which no one can launch hostile acts," Pellegrini said.

That statement was made in September of that year, so after UNSC Resolution 1701 [expanded](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/meetdocs/2009_2014/documents/dmas/dv/unifil_/unifil_en.pdf) the mandate (in August of that year).

I'll note from the JNS article you've linked in your Q that when Hezbollah does something in the UNIFIL area it seem it's usually under some disguise, e.g.

> The [Hezbollah] posts were built under the guise of Green Without Borders, which poses as an environmental NGO.

And an important point is that the Resolution never envisaged that UNIFIL would do this taks alone; it's wording is that UNIFIL would:

> **Assist** the LAF in taking steps towards the establishment between the Blue Line and the Litani river of an free of any armed personnel, assets and weapons other than those of the Government of Lebanon and of UNIFIL deployed in this area;

(Emphasis mine. Also that's an EU Parliament summary of the Resolution. It's [actual](https://digitallibrary.un.org/record/581053?ln=en) wording is more convoluted [with several paras referring to each other] and verbose, but indeed it says before most goals that UNIFIL is merely there to assist Lebanon or its armed forces in doing this or that.) As a Brookings paper [notes](https://www.brookings.edu/articles/debating-un-peacekeeping-in-lebanon/)

> But this mission was always more aspirational than real. Lebanon’s government was never able to deploy the full 15,000 LAF troops (matching UNIFIL’s authorized troop levels one-to-one) that were promised in 2006. Hezbollah fighters and arms are present in the south, and UNIFIL lacks the mandate and capacity to oust them. Given this yawning gap between objectives and achievement, it is no wonder that, every year when UNIFIL’s mandate comes up for renewal at the U.N. Security Council, Washington tries to further strengthen its mandate while also questioning the $500 million annual costs, for which the U.S. assessed share is about 27%.

I'm not sure where exactly this promise of 1:1 matching of UNIFIL troops with LAF's was made. It doesn't seem to be in the Resolution.

I've not seen military analysis of what it would mean for UNIFIL to try to do something more substantive against Hezbollah by themselves, but my 2 cents:

- Since UNIFIL's mandate appears limited to certain areas of Lebanon, they'd be fighting a guerilla that has guaranteed safe bases in the rest of Lebanon, unless UNIFIL's mandate is [geographically] expanded further.
- Hezbollah is a guerilla armed with plenty of rockets and even ballistic missiles, which a UN peacekeeping force may be ill suited to defend themselves against.
- Whenever some strengthening of the UNIFIL mandate comes up at the UN, Hezbollah [threatens](https://www.newarab.com/analysis/unifil-between-hezbollah-and-international-community) to treat UNIFIL as an occupying force, i.e. attack in much more freely that the few incidents where [allegedly] Hezbollah fighters ambushed UNIFIL personnel. Generally speaking, Hezbollah [insofar](https://apnews.com/article/lebanon-hezbollah-unifil-ireland-peacekeeper-5945749323553d7a697316530cb45b39) has denied responsibility for such attacks when they've occurred. (In one such incident, part of a UN convoy strayed outside the planned route to the Beirut airport and entered some village outside of UNIFIL's zone, where their vehicles were almost immediately attacked.)
- I'm not sure how much the various Lebanese governments' position has varied over time on this, but back in 2006 they [declared](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2006-08-26/govt-says-forcibly-disarming-hezbollah-suicidal/1248206) that disarming Hezbollah by force would be "suicidal" for themselves.

Answer (score 13):

This is misunderstanding the nature of UN forces.  In most cases, they are there to help opponents disengage, *when there is already a substantial desire to do so.*

They are not there to fight on the behalf of one or the other group.  And I assume that a review of their equipment in the Lebanon mission would show that they lack the firepower to do so.

It is unhealthy to expect the UN to solve problems between states by force, as it would endanger its status of neutrality, as an actor that both parties in a dispute can turn to.

Just like it is naive to think that the UN is always *the* solution and final arbiter, when several veto members have such atrocious regards for international law and human rights.

The mission in Lebanon has come at some considerable sacrifice - [300+ deaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Interim_Force_in_Lebanon#UNIFIL_casualties) - and it seem unfair to over-criticize it.  Other missions, like the Congo deployment or the Haiti mission has seen UN troops misbehave towards local civilians for example.

> one would expect them to fight until the last soldier

It is hard to take that statement seriously.

Before its current descent into chaos, I would lay the responsibility for keeping the peace on the Lebanese side squarely on the shoulders of the - [ever ineffective](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-lebanon-president-arms-idUSTRE64715V20100508) - Lebanese government.  Not doing so resulted in the 2006 war.

That is one stronger criticism of the UN mission, that the Lebanese government uses the UN forces' presence as a fig leaf to do nothing.  But then again, as we are seeing more and more, not much the Lebanese government does is competent or beneficial to the Lebanese people.

Israel's actions past the 1992 Oslo accord timeline often leave much to be desired, but taking actions to stop shelling from Lebanon in 2006 was well within their rights.

This mission is connected to [UN Resolution 1701](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_1701), which passed post-2006 war (but it predates 1701).

To cite the UN:

> Soon after the resolution's passage, both the UN and UNIFIL contributing nations such as France disclaimed responsibility for disarming Hezbollah.[5] Annan asserted that "dismantling Hezbollah is not the direct mandate of the UN," which could only help Lebanon disarm the organization.[6] Annan (*note: Secretary-General of the UN at the time*) then said on 25 August 2006, ***"The understanding was that it would be the Lebanese who would disarm [Hezbollah]" and that "Obviously, if at some stage they need advice or some help from the international community and they were to approach us, we would consider it, but the troops are not going in there to disarm."[7]**

Comment: But... if they're not there to fight... what's the point of them being there in the first place? Seems like it's still up to Israel to defend their border.

Comment: It is.  However, if the UN mission generally keeps down the temperature most of the time, then it is still beneficial overall, including to Israel (which has a history of painting itself as the victim with all things UN-related).  The 2006 war was no cakewalk for the IDF.  If you look at the wikipedia link, both sides are unhappy and accusing the UN of bias, indicating that it is probably pretty much doing what it should be doing, which is remaining neutral and keeping opponents from each other as much as possible.  Not fighting for Israel.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica is spot on here. The UN has been there for what 50 years,  not as peace makers but peace keepers.  The recent controversy is because the UN is about to hold a vote to renew their presence,  Israel wants the mandate changed,  others lead by France presently want the mandate unchanged, both sides are ratcheting up the press.   The UN just announced they are postponing the renewal vote.

Comment: "Not doing so resulted in the 2006 war." <- Completely disagree. Invading states always bear responsibility for their invasion, even in cases where the invasion was provoked. In the Israeli case this is particularly true considering parts of Lebanon which had been held militarily by Israel (and still held today), and the occasional Israeli attacks and incursions into Lebanese air space.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: Yeah, as I understand how you're stating it, the TL:Dr; would be "The U.N. peacekeeping force is keeping as much peace as they can between both Israel *and* Lebanon. Which includes keeping the peace for Hezbollah when they can. They don't pick sides in a conflict."